# translate.py can't be found in /rnn/translate folder

Tags: tensorflow

I installed tensorflow with method:

```
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

But when I go into the tensorflow folder, I can't found the translate.py file in translate folder, all the files in the translate are list:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that example files were excluded from the pip installation packages of tensorflow (see [issue #4574](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4574)) without updating the docs.

Cloning the [model repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) should help as it contains all the tutorial files.